# Google Custom Search - Have it only index certain pages of a site

Tags: google-search

The pages from my site have ratings from 1 to 10, is there a way I can make [google custom search](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/docs/basics.html) only return pages that have ratings of 7 or higher?

EDIT:Also, I need to be able to have it automatically change as the ratings of the pages change.

Comment: @skaffman Its not SEO, I'm not trying to optimize my google search results in google's main index, its for the custom search engines that allow users to search for content within my site. The little google search box that gets placed on my site.

Comment: My apologies. However, please don't invent new tags, we have more than enough already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/docs/start.html) seem to indicate you can tell it which pages to search using the control panel.